# Implementation of Menus in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I am new to android.I want to create a list which consists several items like Drug Name,Administration,etc.If we Click on DrugName,It should Open a page in the same page consisting of menus as shown in the below figure.Please Some examples Like this.Please Help..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do is expandable listview:

[Heres the Tutorial for android expandable listview](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Comment: hiii..Thanks For the Link..If i want to add a simple registration page instead of menus,i.e.;if I click Administration,A administration Page should open as showmn in the above figure How can I do that.Please suggest

Comment: I think u should design the childview as the admin page and set it as the childview of the parent view

Comment: Can You Please Explain where do I need to do the changes.Please Help

Comment: On that tutorial list_item.xml is the child layout design that layout as administration page.